# “Type DATE is not a defined system type.”

Tags: sql-server

Right now I'm developing a program but had an issues with

> Type DATE is not a defined system type.

I wrote my queries with SQL Server 2008 on local and it run very well, but when change to live server, it went wrong and prompt above error. For live server my company using SQL Server 2000.

Below is my query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CONVERT(varchar, A.MONTH) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar, A.YEAR) AS MonthYear
FROM
    XXX1 AS A 
LEFT JOIN
    XXX2 AS B ON A.EMPLOYEE_NO = B.EMPLOYEE_NO 
LEFT JOIN
    XXX3 AS C ON A.EMPLOYEE_NO = C.EMPLOYEE_NO 
LEFT JOIN 
    XXX4 AS D on A.FREQUENCY = D.FREQUENCY 
WHERE
    (A.EMPLOYEE_NO = '710049') AND (A.FREQUENCY = '9') 
    AND ((day(getdate()) >= DAY(d.TRANS_DATE) OR 
          month(getdate()) = MONTH(d.TRANS_DATE) OR
          YEAR(getdate()) = YEAR(d.TRANS_DATE))
         OR (month(getdate()) - MONTH(d.TRANS_DATE) <> 0 
         OR day(getdate()) < DAY(d.TRANS_DATE)))
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Yep, the `date` data type has first appeared in 2008 version. It's absent in 2000.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in that where you are using date!

Comment: @russ yup. i also dont understand why it appear that error.

Comment: If you attempted to create the tables with Date, you could edit the CREATE table statements and change Date to Datetime. Wherever Date appears make it Datetime. SQL Server 2000 will recognise that and it will just put a bunch of zeroes for the time (00:00:00).

Comment: I assume you want to use a `date` field because you don't want the `time` portion of a `datetime`.  You can eliminate the time portion of the value before/as you store it in the database by casting it as an `int`.  When I tried it, the `int` portion was rounded to the next day if the time was after noon.  So I used `declare @now datetime = cast(cast(getdate() as float) as int); select @now`, and it returned just today's date without rounding to tomorrow's date.

Comment: You company should not be using SQL 2000 for a live system (it is well out of support), and it should not be developing for a platform using a different version, and testing should have revealed this before approaching the production system.  17 years have elapsed since SQL 2000, plenty of time to plan an upgrade.